# Combination of prefixed and wildcard pattern based subscribtion

Tags: wamp, crossbar

Is there any possibility of combine the "prefix" and "wildcard" subscription options? 
I want to subscribe to a channel with the following pattern:

channel..messages.*

In my application there is a logging component that should log for all channels the values of the different messages types, like this:

```
channel.<string:ChannelId>.messages.<string:MessageType>
```

Is there any chance of subscribing to such a topic with crossbar / wamp? 
Or is there a better solution for such a use case?